# I need to get an old version of ember running with ember cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hi all I have an application I build for a client a while back. 
please see the the application ember version data below.

```
Ember Inspector
1.10.0
Ember
1.13.7
Ember Data
1.13.8
jQuery
2.1.4
Ember Simple Auth
0.8.0
```

I now need to make a change, but I am having issues running ember cli. Any idea what version of npm, node and ember cli i should use.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall the existing ember-cli and install specific version you required. in your case you can try 1.13.7

```
npm uninstall -g ember-cli -- Remove old global ember-cli
npm cache clean -- Clear NPM cache
npm install -g ember-cli@1.13.7 -- Install new global ember-cli
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had to downgrade my node version and do some cleanup but overall it worked. thanks.
node version v0.12.2